# flask reload module on windows

Tags: python, flask

I am on Windows, using python 2.7, flask installed with pip. I am trying to get flask reload my python module after source code change. I did

```
SET FLASK_APP=backend.py
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

this causes the following error:

```
* Serving Flask app "backend"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
c:\python27\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Python27\Scripts\flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So I tried (as suggested by some others)

```
python -m flask run
```

which however caused the following error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "backend"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 168-045-575
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 243-777-971
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jan/2017 15:22:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\MyWebApp\backend.py", line 21, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 843, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 692, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 242, in run_with_reloader
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *args: sys.exit(0))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

How can I get flask to run with automatic re-loader on Windows?

Comment: what version of werkzeug do you have?  according to the [flask bug tracker](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1829) this is fixed in werkzeug 0.11.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in werkzeug 0.11.13 as mentioned by snakecharmerb. After

```
pip install werkzeug --upgrade
```

reload is working as expected.