# Flask not auto-reloading when running under WSL2 and I do not have 'watchdog' installed

Tags: python, flask, watchdog

I am writing a Flask app, but it does not auto-refresh when I save my code changes, I have not `watchdog` installed, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594734/flask-does-not-reload-modified-code-when-running-under-wsl) does not work for me! Somebody can help me?

By the way, my code is just a file `main.py` with the following code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello Stack Overflow!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8888)
```

My environment variables are:

```sh
export FLASK_APP=main.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8888
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: Where is your app located? If it is on a Windows drive, `inotify` does not work with WSL2. It does work within the Linux filesystem though. Or you just scrap WSL2 and use a real developer system ;-)

Comment: My file location is in `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/Dev/flask-expample/src`

Comment: Is there any way to not stop using WSL? The werdiest thing is that I am pretty sure it worked fine before, don't know why stop working.

Comment: Or can you tell me how do I move my project within the Linux filesystem?

Comment: Move your project under /home/<username> and it will work again. Probably it worked before when you were using WSL1. Another benefit of working in /home/<username> instead of /mnt/c is that it will be much faster because the Windows filesystem sucks.